# Android's view not refreshing

Tags: android

In a thread when I receive something from internet I want to notify the user and I do something like

```
new Thread(new Runnable(...
   ...
   Log.d("tag", "going to redraw");
   findViewById(R.id.view).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   findViewById(R.id.view).refreshDrawableState();  // tried this
   findViewById(R.id.view).invalidate();  // and this together and separately
 ).start();
```

I *always* see the log, and *sometimes* see the view shown. I have no idea what's going on

I have tried to include the `findViewById` in a `runOnUIThread` but that didn't do the job either. Any tip on this ?

Comment: Did you try `postInvalidate()` instead of `invalidate()`?

Comment: @codeMagic still not working

Comment: Do you have the `VISIBILITY` before this as `GONE` or `INVISIBLE`?

Comment: you don't call to call `invalidate` after changing the visibility--it's called internally

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not modify the UI in a Thread other than the UI Thread! Either use a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) or [Activity.runOnUiThread()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29)

Comment: Actually I was doing  `if ... findViewById(...)...GONE else VISIBLE` and then `runOnUIThread(...invalidate)`. Putting everything into the `UIThread` seems to work for now

}

Answer (score 0):

When you are not on the main `Thread` you need to use `postInvalidate()` on the `View` instead of `invalidate()`

[From the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#postInvalidate%28%29)

> Cause an invalidate to happen on a subsequent cycle through the event loop. Use this to invalidate the View from a non-UI thread.

[From the docs for invalidate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate%28%29)

> This must be called from a UI thread.